# Why the `git config tar.tar.xz.command "xz -c"` command can configure a "tar.xz" format for making LZMA-compressed tarfiles when using git-archive?

Tags: git, tar, git-config, git-archive

I encountered [this example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt-codegitconfigtartarxzcommandxz-ccode) in Git official documents when learning `git-archive`.

```
git config tar.tar.xz.command "xz -c" # set this config
git archive -o latest.tar.xz HEAD  # So you can create an archive that is compressed with LZMA algorithm.
```

But Why does this trick work? Is the `tar.<extension-name>.command` an convention? And where the convention comes from?

I had read the manpage of `git-archive`, `git-config`, and `tar`, searched this question and related keyword in Google but unfortunately still can't find the answer...

Thank you very much for your kindly help!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt-tarltformatgtcommand

Comment: @phd, thank you. Oh my god, I am too careless to miss it.